# Can't import self created NPM package in Typescript code

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a web project written in Typescript (2.1.6) and compiled with Webpack in VScode.
I have a logging client as a third party that I'm currently trying to upload to NPM and use it as a normal dependency.

That logging client was originally written in the "old" Typescript syntax using the old Typescript modules (those that compile into Javascript objects), so I rewrote the code to use the import/export syntax.
I'm compiling the refactored logging code with the module flag set to "umd" and with ES5 as the target script.
I'm creating a single d.ts file for it using the dts-generator npm package.

Currently it looks kinda like this: (I don't really have the code in front of me, but this is the general idea)

The refactored code for the Logger.ts looks something like this:

```
import { LoggerSettings } from "./LoggerSetting";
import { AjaxRequest } from "./AjaxRequest";

// ... more of the same
export class Logger {
    // Implementation
}
```

The d.ts that is created looks something like this:

```
declare module "logging-client" {
    export class LoggerSettings {
        // ...
    }
}

declare module "logging-client" {
    export class Logger {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "logging-client",
    "main": "Logger.js",
    "types": "logging-client.d.ts"
}
```

When trying to import the Logger into my typescript code, I'm getting a "can't find the logging-client module".

How can I even start diagnosing such a problem?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance, Avi :)

EDIT: If anyone's interested, here's a git repo with the problem:
https://github.com/avrahams1/LogError

Comment: I think that in package.json you should have `"typings": "logging-client.d.ts"` instead of `"types": "logging-client.d.ts"`

Comment: According to the official Typescript site (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) they're the same. Plus that didn't work either :(

Comment: Yepp, you are right about that. One more thing - in the example on github I do not see that 'logger-user' has 'logger' listed in the dependencies in package.json. Without it - npm will never install it and tsc will never find it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the actual code, its a mockup to illustrate the problem so I just copied the output into the node_modules of the other project.

Comment: You can try compiling your `logger-user` project with --traceResolution flag to see whats happening (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Comment: Thanks, it cleared up the problem! Still working on it though - the problem is that when resolving modules using ES6 you can't import a module that doesn't have a definition file, and not only that but specifically one in the node_modules/@types folder, apparently the types field in the config.json doesn't do anything.

Comment: Great - I put it as an answer then.

Comment: You can import it but using `require` syntax. And surely you will have no typed definitions in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a while, just want to close this one.
There isn't a way to re-conciliate old and new Typescript syntax, I had to re-write the old logger to conform to the ES6 module syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try compiling your logger-user project with `--traceResolution` flag to see whats happening.

More info here: [module-resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)